# Import Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

I'm having issues with my jquery code. I'm new to jquery so I'm not really sure where the problem lies.

```
-- phpMiniAdmin dump 1.9.150917
-- Datetime: 2019-10-31 23:14:13
-- Host:

--/*!40030 SET NAMES utf8 */;
--/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Hunter`;
CREATE TABLE `Hunter` (
  `Hunterid` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Huntername` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `HunterWeapon` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `HunterSemblance` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Hunterid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Hunter` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Hunter`(Hunterid, Huntername, HunterWeapon, HunterSemblance) VALUES (333,'Ruby Rose','Crescent Rose', 'Speed'),(111,'Weiss Schnee','Myrtenaster', 'Glyphs'), (222,'Yang Xiao Long','Ember Celica', 'Deflection');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Hunter` ENABLE KEYS */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Training Academy`;
CREATE TABLE `Training Academy` (
  `Training Academyid` char(7) NOT NULL,
  `Training Academyname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Training Academycountry` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Training Academyid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Training Academy` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Training Academy` (Training Academyid, Training Academyname, Training Academycountry) VALUES ('1111111','Beacon','Vale'),('2222222','Haven','Mistral'),('3333333','Shade','Vacuo');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Training Academy` ENABLE KEYS */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Head Master`;
CREATE TABLE `Head Master` (
  `Head Masterid` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Head Mastername` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Training Academyid` char(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Head Masterid`),
  KEY `Training Academyid` (`Training Academyid`),
  CONSTRAINT `Head Master_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Training Academyid`) REFERENCES `Training Academyid` (`Training Academyid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Head Master` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Head Master` (Head Masterid,Head Mastername) VALUES (777,'Ozpin'), (888,'Lionheart'), (444,'Ironwood');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Head Master` ENABLE KEYS */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Villian Team`;
CREATE TABLE `Villian Team` (
  `Villian Teamid` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `Villian Teamname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Villian Teamid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Villian Team` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Villian Team` (Villian Teamid, Villian Teamname) VALUES (7979,'White Fang'),(1452,'Cinders Team');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Villian Team` ENABLE KEYS */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Hunter Team`;
CREATE TABLE `Hunter Team` (
  `Hunter Teamname` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `Hunter Teamid` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `Training Academyid` char(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Hunter Teamid`),
  KEY `Training Academyid` (`Training Academyid`),
  CONSTRAINT `Hunter Team_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Training Academyid`) REFERENCES `Training Academy` (`Training Academyid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Hunter Team` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Hunter Team` (Hunter Teamname, Hunter Teamid) VALUES (51515,'RWBY'), (78787,'JNPR'), (47155,'STRQ');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Hunter Team` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

Comment: You pasted a bunch of code here, but did nothing to try to explain to us where/what the problem might be.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? That's a JavaScript library, it has nothing to do with MySQL or databases.

Comment: If you get an error trying to load a file that was created with `mysqldump`, it's usually because you're trying to load into an incompatible version of MySQL than the one where it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Lines like this are the problem:

```
INSERT INTO `Training Academy` (Training Academyid, Training Academyname, Training Academycountry) VALUES ('1111111','Beacon','Vale'),('2222222','Haven','Mistral'),('3333333','Shade','Vacuo');
```

You have column names with spaces in them, you need to put backticks around them.

```
INSERT INTO `Training Academy` (`Training Academyid`, `Training Academyname`, `Training Academycountry`) VALUES ('1111111','Beacon','Vale'),('2222222','Haven','Mistral'),('3333333','Shade','Vacuo');
```

You have the same problem when inserting into `Head Master`, `Villain Team`, and `Hunter Team`.

For more information, see [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

If this was created using a database export command from `phpMiniAdmin`, I suggest you throw it out -- this is an unforgiveable bug. `phpMyAdmin` is more popular and probably less buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 issues here.

> 1. Missing backticks on column names.
> 2. Missing default values on foreign keys, so it failed during insert if not supplied
> 3. You've interchanged the column, so this line will fail.

```
INSERT INTO `Hunter Team` (`Hunter Teamname`, `Hunter Teamid`) VALUES (51515,'RWBY'), (78787,'JNPR'), (47155,'STRQ');
```

Here's your complete working script.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Hunter`;
CREATE TABLE `Hunter` (
  `Hunterid` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Huntername` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `HunterWeapon` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `HunterSemblance` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Hunterid`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `Hunter`(Hunterid, Huntername, HunterWeapon, HunterSemblance) VALUES (333,'Ruby Rose','Crescent Rose', 'Speed'),(111,'Weiss Schnee','Myrtenaster', 'Glyphs'), (222,'Yang Xiao Long','Ember Celica', 'Deflection');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Training Academy`;
CREATE TABLE `Training Academy` (
  `Training Academyid` char(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1111111',
  `Training Academyname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Training Academycountry` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Training Academyid`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `Training Academy` (`Training Academyid`, `Training Academyname`, `Training Academycountry`) VALUES ('1111111','Beacon','Vale'),('2222222','Haven','Mistral'),('3333333','Shade','Vacuo');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Head Master`;
CREATE TABLE `Head Master` (
  `Head Masterid` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Head Mastername` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Training Academyid` char(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1111111',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Head Masterid`),
  KEY `Training Academyid` (`Training Academyid`),
  CONSTRAINT `Head Master_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Training Academyid`) REFERENCES `Training Academy` (`Training Academyid`)
);


INSERT INTO `Head Master` (`Head Masterid`,`Head Mastername`) VALUES (777,'Ozpin'), (888,'Lionheart'), (444,'Ironwood');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Villian Team`;
CREATE TABLE `Villian Team` (
  `Villian Teamid` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `Villian Teamname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Villian Teamid`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `Villian Team` (`Villian Teamid`, `Villian Teamname`) VALUES (7979,'White Fang'),(1452,'Cinders Team');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Hunter Team`;
CREATE TABLE `Hunter Team` (
  `Hunter Teamname` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `Hunter Teamid` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `Training Academyid` char(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1111111',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Hunter Teamid`),
  KEY `Training Academyid` (`Training Academyid`),
  CONSTRAINT `Hunter Team_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Training Academyid`) REFERENCES `Training Academy` (`Training Academyid`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `Hunter Team` (`Hunter Teamid`,`Hunter Teamname`) VALUES (51515,'RWBY'), (78787,'JNPR'), (47155,'STRQ');
```